# my Development provisioning profile is invalid. Can i regenerate it?

Tags: xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I'm about to update my app that is now in App Store.But when I was preparing my updates development in Xcode, I accidentally revoked my certificates and I regenerate them. After regenerating all of my certificates, I made a ipaFile and I'm now trying to upload it to iTunes connect.But before that, I found that the Development provisioning file was invalid.(not the distribution one)

And I have about three questions with this situation.

•Is it necessary to regenerate my development provisioning files?

•And if I regenerate my development provisioning file, do I have to regenerate my ceritificates again?

•Are there any problems by uploading an ipa file while my development provisioning file is invalid?

Comment: chek your keychain   may be your  development cf Private key missing

Comment: Thanks for commenting.But it appears that those keys are already in my key chain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can generate Proviosing Profile.

Go to Developer Account ->Click on Invalied Proviosing Profile ->Edit      ->Certificate select your developer Certificate -> Rename provisiong Profile -> Click on Generate -> Done -> Download

Please Follow Following Steps.